# Object Must Implement IConvertible LINQ to Entities query containing grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in which i am using entity model for connecting to MySQl database

Here I am joining 2 tables and then applying group by on one of the fields. Then fetching the result from GroupBy result.
Everything is working fine on development machine but getting next error:

> Object Must Implement IConvertible

Can you please help me out why such error is occurring. I have taken the dump of database form staging server and then used that on development machine then also working fine. But when I placed the dump of development machine database on staging then getting the same exception.

So where is problem i am not understanding.

The model structure is

```
student:
studentid int 
course string
name string

student_payment:
id int 
studentid int 
amount decimal
```

Here student and  student_payment  has association on studentid of one to many.

Query:

```
var query = from s in entity.student_payment.Include("student")
            group s by s.registrant.course into grp 
            select new 
            { 
                course = grp.Key, 
                count = (from studentcnt in grp select studentcnt.student.studentid), 
                payment = (from payment in grp select payment)
            };

foreach (var q in query) // exception is occurring here
{
    studentcount == q.count.Distinct().Count()
    iamount = payment.Sum(r => r.amount);
}
```

In the query i have applied the GroupBy on the course and then fetching the record from the associated tables.

Comment: Please post your model and queries.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you edit this into the question rather than leave it as comments. Then you can use formatting and indentation to make it readable and understandable (so far it isn't). If you expect to get an answer, please put some effort into the question.

Comment: I use to accept the answer when they really solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the error .I think when we are having association between the tables then with group by we cannot apply select subqueries.

So I use the select query while parsing the result set of groupby.

```
var query = from s in entity.student_payment.Include("student")
            group s by s.registrant.course into grp 
            select new 
            { 
                course = grp.Key,     
            };

foreach (var q in query) // exception is occurring here
{
    var count = (from studentcnt in entity.student_payment.Include("student") where  student.course==q.course select studentcnt );               

    payment = (from payment in grp select payment)

    studentcount == count.Select(r=>r.student.studentid).Distinct().Count()

    iamount = count.Sum(r => r.amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try update your MySQL Server to 5.5x or newest.

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/